# Why dpkg-query -l with a wildcard does not list all possible packages?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

According to `dpkg-query` manual page:

> For  example  this  will list all package
> names starting with “libc6”:
>
> ```
>             dpkg-query -l 'libc6*'
> ```

When I try it on Debian 10.5:

```
$ dpkg-query -l 'libc6*'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  libc6:amd64    2.28-10      amd64        GNU C Library: Shared libraries
un  libc6-amd64    <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  libc6.1        <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

While `apt` shows more packages:

```
$ apt list 'libc6*'
Listing... Виконано
libc6-amd64-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-amd64-i386-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-amd64-x32-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-arm64-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-armel-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-armhf-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dbg/stable 2.28-10 amd64
libc6-dev-amd64-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-amd64-i386-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-amd64-x32-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-arm64-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-armel-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-armhf-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-hppa-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-i386-amd64-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-i386-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-i386-x32-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-i386/stable 2.28-10 amd64
libc6-dev-m68k-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-mips-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-mips32-mips64-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-dev-mips32-mips64el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-mips32-mips64r6-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-dev-mips32-mips64r6el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-dev-mips32-mipsn32-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-dev-mips32-mipsn32el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-dev-mips32-mipsn32r6-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-dev-mips32-mipsn32r6el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-dev-mips64-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-dev-mips64-mips-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-mips64-mipsel-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-mips64-mipsn32-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-dev-mips64-mipsn32el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-dev-mips64-mipsn32r6-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-dev-mips64-mipsn32r6el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-dev-mips64-mipsr6-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-dev-mips64-mipsr6el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-dev-mips64el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-mips64r6-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-dev-mips64r6el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-dev-mipsel-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-mipsn32-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-dev-mipsn32-mips-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-mipsn32-mips64-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-dev-mipsn32-mips64el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-mipsn32-mips64r6-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-dev-mipsn32-mips64r6el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-dev-mipsn32-mipsel-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-mipsn32-mipsr6-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-dev-mipsn32-mipsr6el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-dev-mipsn32el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-dev-mipsn32r6-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-dev-mipsn32r6el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-dev-mipsr6-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-dev-mipsr6el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-dev-powerpc-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-powerpc-ppc64-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-powerpcspe-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-ppc64-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-ppc64-powerpc-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-ppc64el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-riscv64-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-s390-s390x-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-s390x-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-sh4-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-sparc-sparc64-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-sparc64-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-x32-amd64-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-x32-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-x32-i386-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-dev-x32/stable 2.28-10 amd64
libc6-dev/stable 2.28-10 amd64
libc6-hppa-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-i386-amd64-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-i386-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-i386-x32-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-i386/stable 2.28-10 amd64
libc6-m68k-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-mips-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-mips32-mips64-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-mips32-mips64el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-mips32-mips64r6-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-mips32-mips64r6el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-mips32-mipsn32-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-mips32-mipsn32el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-mips32-mipsn32r6-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-mips32-mipsn32r6el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-mips64-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-mips64-mips-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-mips64-mipsel-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-mips64-mipsn32-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-mips64-mipsn32el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-mips64-mipsn32r6-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-mips64-mipsn32r6el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-mips64-mipsr6-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-mips64-mipsr6el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-mips64el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-mips64r6-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-mips64r6el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-mipsel-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-mipsn32-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-mipsn32-mips-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-mipsn32-mips64-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-mipsn32-mips64el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-mipsn32-mips64r6-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-mipsn32-mips64r6el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-mipsn32-mipsel-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-mipsn32-mipsr6-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-mipsn32-mipsr6el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-mipsn32el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-mipsn32r6-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-mipsn32r6el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-mipsr6-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-mipsr6el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross2 all
libc6-pic/stable 2.28-10 amd64
libc6-powerpc-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-powerpc-ppc64-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-powerpcspe-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-ppc64-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-ppc64-powerpc-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-ppc64el-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-riscv64-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-s390-s390x-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-s390x-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-sh4-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-sparc-sparc64-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-sparc64-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-x32-amd64-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-x32-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-x32-i386-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6-x32/stable 2.28-10 amd64
libc6.1-alpha-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6.1-dev-alpha-cross/stable 2.28-7cross1 all
libc6/stable,now 2.28-10 amd64 [installed]
```

How to make `dpkg-query` show all matches? Why does it show only a selection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dpkg-query` only looks at `/var/lib/dpkg/status` by default, and that only contains information about packages which are currently installed or were installed in the past.

To see all the available packages, you can add the `--load-avail` option:

```
dpkg-query --load-avail -l 'libc6*'
```

but that relies on `/var/lib/dpkg/available` being up-to-date. `apt` doesn’t touch that file, it uses its own databases, so you’ll need to take care of that yourself:

```
for file in /var/lib/apt/lists/*_Packages; do sudo dpkg --merge-avail $file; done
```

(Note that this doesn’t take care of translated descriptions, so `dpkg-query` won’t be able to show them.)

It’s best to use `apt` for such queries. `dpkg` has a local view of packages, `apt` has a repository-based view; so repository-based queries are better handled by `apt`.